# Messed-up GUI: Lot of Blank Space

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea, gridbaglayout

Please have a look at the following code

```
package email;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SendEmail extends JDialog
{
    private JLabel to, cc, bcc, subject, account;
    private JTextField toTxt, ccTxt, bccTxt, subjectTxt;
    private JTextArea messageTxt;
    private JButton send;

    private JComboBox accountBox;

    private JScrollPane scroll;

    private GridBagLayout gbl;
    private GridBagConstraints gbc;

    public SendEmail()
    {
        //Declaring instance variables
        to = new JLabel("To: ");
        cc = new JLabel("CC: ");
        bcc = new JLabel("BCC: ");
        subject = new JLabel("Subject: ");
        account = new JLabel("Select an Account: ");

        toTxt = new JTextField(20);
        ccTxt = new JTextField(20);
        bccTxt = new JTextField(20);
        subjectTxt = new JTextField(20);

        messageTxt = new JTextArea(500,500);
        scroll = new JScrollPane(messageTxt);


        accountBox = new JComboBox();
        accountBox.addItem("Yahoo");
        accountBox.addItem("GMail");
        accountBox.addItem("MSN");
        //accountBox.addItem("Yahoo");
        //accountBox.addItem("Yahoo");



        //Creating thr GUI
        gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        this.setLayout(gbl);


        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        this.add(account,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        this.add(accountBox,gbc);


        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        this.add(to,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        this.add(toTxt,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        this.add(bcc,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        this.add(bccTxt,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        this.add(cc,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        this.add(ccTxt,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        this.add(subject,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        this.add(subjectTxt,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 6;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        this.add(scroll,gbc);


        this.setSize(new Dimension(200,500));
        this.setVisible(true);


    }
}
```

In here, the GUI seems very bad. I need to have enough space for all the fields. In the `JTextArea`, you can see it is not even visible. I need it's height to be 2 columns; it seems like all these problems are occurring because it is trying to set the large `JTextArea` to one column. For your information, this is an "Compose Email" GUI, so you can be clear of what I am asking. I used `this.pack()` but it made everything worst!

Comment: Don't call `setSize()`. Instead `pack()` the GUI and let the component's natural preferred sizes and the layouts dictate the size of the GUI. If `pack()` makes things worse, then you should fix the problem from that side of things, not by calling `setSize()`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels:  thanks for the reply. But what do I need to do?

Comment: @Yohan: Please calm down and watch your language -- there are kids who use this site. Don't make me regret trying to help you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: That never applies to you :) . You have helped me number of times. I can remember your name because you have answered my previous questions. But, there is a person in this site, following my posts and voting to close them. I thought this is done by him. And, I removed it :)

Comment: there is no way around in-depth learning of how-to use at least one complex LayoutManager - my suggestion would be to go third-party (f.i. MigLayout or FormLayout), as you get more power, flexibility and stability for the investment

Comment: @kleopatra: To be honest, I have heard lot of companies are using GridBagLayout. That's why I am trying to stick with it :)

Comment: It doesn't matter who it applies to. Your response will only get folks upset and more likely to close this question. @kelopatra has some valuable points as well. GridBagLayout is a pain in the arse. Another option is to nest layouts and only use GBL when absolutely needed. For instance the whole thing could be a BorderLayout with the JScrollPane in the CENTER and the GBL fields in the NORTH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned above in the comments:

> Don't call `setSize()`. Instead `pack()` the GUI and let the component's natural preferred sizes and the layouts dictate the size of the GUI. If `pack()` makes things worse, then you should fix the problem from that side of things, not by calling `setSize()`.

For instance, I would

- make the JTextArea a *reasonable* size, not 500 rows by 500 cols!
- Don't set size of things
- Do call `pack()`
- Don't forget to use weightx and weighty (added to the code) and insets (not yet added).
- Avoid magic numbers.
- Consider nesting easier to use layouts and minimizing use of GridBagLayout.
- Give the JScrollPane extra gridwidth to allow it to fill up the bottom.  For instance:

SendEmail.java:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SendEmail extends JDialog {
   public final static String[] LABEL_TEXTS = { "Select an Account:", "To:",
         "BCC:", "CC:", "Subject:" };
   public final static String[] ACCOUNT_TEXTS = { "Yahoo", "GMail", "MSN" };
   private static final int TEXT_FIELD_LENGTH = 20;
   private static final int T_AREA_ROWS = 20;
   private static final int T_AREA_COLS = 50;
   private static final int INSET_GAP = 1;
   private static final int RIGHT_INSET_GAP = 15;
   private Map<String, JTextField> fieldMap = new HashMap<String, JTextField>();
   private JTextArea messageTxt;
   private JButton send;

   private JComboBox<String> accountBox;

   private JScrollPane scroll;

   public SendEmail(JFrame frame) {
      super(frame, "Dialog", true);
      messageTxt = new JTextArea(T_AREA_ROWS, T_AREA_COLS);
      scroll = new JScrollPane(messageTxt);
      accountBox = new JComboBox<String>(ACCOUNT_TEXTS);

      this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      int ebGap = 5;
      ((JPanel) getContentPane()).setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(
            ebGap, ebGap, ebGap, ebGap));

      for (int i = 0; i < LABEL_TEXTS.length; i++) {
         JLabel label = new JLabel(LABEL_TEXTS[i]);
         addLabel(0, i, label);

         if (i == 0) {
            addField(1, i, accountBox);
         } else {
            JTextField tField = new JTextField(TEXT_FIELD_LENGTH);
            fieldMap.put(LABEL_TEXTS[i], tField);
            addField(1, i, tField);
         }
      }

      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = LABEL_TEXTS.length;
      gbc.gridwidth = 2;
      gbc.weightx = 1.0;
      gbc.weighty = 1.0;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(INSET_GAP, INSET_GAP, INSET_GAP, INSET_GAP);
      this.add(scroll, gbc);

      pack();
      this.setVisible(true);
   }

   private void addField(int x, int y, JComponent comp) {
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridx = x;
      gbc.gridy = y;
      gbc.weightx = 1.0;
      gbc.weighty = 0.0;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(INSET_GAP, INSET_GAP, INSET_GAP, INSET_GAP);
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;

      this.add(comp, gbc);
   }

   private void addLabel(int x, int y, JComponent comp) {
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridx = x;
      gbc.gridy = y;
      gbc.weightx = 0.0;
      gbc.weighty = 0.0;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(INSET_GAP, INSET_GAP, INSET_GAP, RIGHT_INSET_GAP);
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;

      this.add(comp, gbc);
   }

   public String getTextFieldText(String key) {
      JTextField tField = fieldMap.get(key);
      if (tField == null) {
         String text = "key, " + key + " not a valid argument for fieldMap";
         throw new IllegalArgumentException(text);
      }

      return tField.getText();
   }

   public String getAccountText() {
      return accountBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
   }

   public String getMessageTxt() {
      return messageTxt.getText();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.pack();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      new SendEmail(frame);
      frame.dispose();
   }
}
```

which when run would look like:

[image]

Comment: Edit: weightx and weighty added.

Comment: awesome..Just awesome..No words, but awesome!! Thank you!

Comment: wait wait!! What does that weightx, weighty do? It seems like it is resizing. Is that is what it is used for? Then, my next question has been automatically answered!!

Comment: @Yohan: Try with and without weightx and weighty (comment and uncomment them) and then resize the resulting gui's.